# Username and password injected in my table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-injection, code-injection

I am new to asp.net development

I develop login form with username and password

I finished off with my work but any how my `login` table has injected with sort of script as

username

```
"> </title><script src="http://it
```

password

```
"> </title><script src="http://it
```

I have written simple query as

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = 'admin' AND password = 'ms2012'
```

I thought some body has injected in a username and password textbox

But I don't understand how they did. Can anybody explain **how they have updated it** and **what should I do to avoid it?**

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection - Basically you need to quote your input so the queries you write into your database are not being directly sourced from the user as to allow malicious behavior like what you have experienced.

Comment: @TMan I wouldn't say *quoting* or *escaping* are recommended approaches. Parameterised queries are really the best method

Comment: @Phil Great call, completely forgot about parameterized queries!

Comment: yes i used sql parameterised query to avoid the sql injection and it works!!

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 basic things to consider if you want to the application to be secured from SQL Injection:

1. Paramterized Queries
2. Stored Procedures
3. Sanitizing all input data